# Projection of Uniform Distribution between 2 Simplex

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, probability, projective-geometry

1. $X$ is a uniform distribution on the [standard simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#The_standard_simplex) $L$. For any point $\vec{x}$ on $X$, all entries of $\vec{x}$ are between 0 and 1 and $\vec{x}\cdot \vec{1} = 1$.
2. $S$ is the standard simplex scaled by a positive $w_{i}$ along each dimension. That means each point $(x_{1}, x_{2}, ...)$ on $X$ becomes $(w_{1}x_{1}, w_{2}x_{2}, ...)$ on $S$.
3. The scaling of all axes is a one to one transformation $T$ from $L$ to $S$.

If I apply transformation $T$ to $X$, do I get a uniform distribution over non-standard simplex S?

Is this still true if some of the $w_i = 0$?

Is the following reasoning correct if all $w_i \ne 0$?

1. Determinant of the Jacobian for the change of coordinate is constant
2. By change of coordinate formula in multi-variable calculus, area of any infinitesimal area over the standard simplex is scaled by the same constant when the area is transformed by $T$.
3. Therefore, the probability density is scaled by the same constant upon the transformation.
4. Consequently, I get a uniform distribution over $S$.

Thank you.

Comment: Your reasoning does not really deal with the $w_i=0$ issue.  You might consider what happens with $w_1=1, w_2=0, w_3=0$. The distribution will then not be uniform

Comment: If I pick some $w_i$ that are not zero but very close to zero, will that be ok? I am fine with faking it with small numbers as long as the positive $w_{i}$ case works.

Comment: I think about the standard simplex in 2D, which is the hypotenuse of an equilateral right triangle. When I scale the vertical axis to 0, the result stay the same if the length of the original line segment is the same. So zeros are fine in the 2D case.

Comment: But should be same for the 3D case too. I think about the equilateral triangle A with vertices at (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1). The ratio between any shape (I pick a small equilateral triangle) on A and shadow of the shape on the plane z = 1 would stay constant regardless of the location of the shape. Therefore, it works for the 3D case too.

Comment: Your comment on the $3D$ case projects onto a plane, but my suggestion was to project onto a line.  You will find that $x_1$ is more likely to be less than $\frac12$ than greater than $\frac12$.  And this would also be true if $w_1=1$ while $w_2$ and $w_3$ were very small and positive: that would be uniform, but perhaps not not in the way you might intuitively predict

Comment: With a uniform distribution on the original simplex, the marginal distribution of each $x_i$ is not uniform for $n \gt 2$.  Multiplying by $w_i$ simply rescales the marginal distribution linearly, so it stays not uniform.  And the values of $w_j$ for $j \not = i$ do not affect the marginal distribution of $w_ix_i$

Comment: Found the procedure for multivariable transformation of random variable: http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~ayoung/m2s1/Multivariatetransformations.PDF Let me try that.

Comment: Devroye p.569 Says a linear transformation of an uniform distribution on the standard simplex becomes another uniform distribution on another simplex. Is Devroye wrong? http://www.eirene.de/Devroye.pdf

Comment: Ok. I get what you mean now. 1. The reasoning works if all $w_i$ are not zero. 2. A very thin triangle is not a line. 3. The reasoning does not work if some $w_i$ are zero. For example, projecting an uniform distribution on a 3-simplex onto a 1-simplex would not produce an uniform distribution on the 1-simplex. 4. The book is correct.